# .gitkeep files doesn't exist after push

Tags: git

I've set `.gitignore` file with the following lines

This are working:

```
application/cache/*
!application/cache/index.html
```

But this doesn't work:

```
web/uploads/*
!web/uploads/filters/.gitkeep
!web/uploads/payments/.gitkeep
!web/uploads/surveys/.gitkeep
```

There is no `/web/uploads` or `web/uploads/filters/.gitkeep`,`web/uploads/payments/.gitkeep` or `web/uploads/surveys/.gitkeep` files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Comment: You need to unignore subdirectories: `!web/uploads/filters/` and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a big difference between the rules that work and those that do not work. Those that work operate on a top-level directory and a file inside it. Those that do not work contain intermediate directories.

```
web/uploads/*
```

This ignore rule tells Git to ignore all the files and subdirectories of `web/uploads`.
The exclusion rules that follow it:

```
!web/uploads/filters/.gitkeep
!web/uploads/payments/.gitkeep
!web/uploads/surveys/.gitkeep
```

do not match any files because the `filters`, `payments` and `surveys` directories (and their content) are ignored because of the previous rule.

There is no simple solution for this problem (or, at least, none that I am aware of).

A solution exists (but it is verbose): you have to tell Git to ignore everything in `web/uploads` except for the `filters`, `payments` and `surveys` subdirectories then, for each of them to ignore everything inside it except for `.gitkeep`.

As `.gitignore` rules, the paragraph above is represented as follows:

```
# Ignore everything in web/uploads
web/uploads/*

# ... except for the 'filters' subdirectory...
!web/uploads/filters
# ... but ignore everything inside it...
web/uploads/filters/*
# ... except for .gitkeep
!web/uploads/filters/.gitkeep

# The same rules as above for 'payments'
!web/uploads/payments
web/uploads/payments/*
!web/uploads/payments/.gitkeep

# ... and surveys
!web/uploads/surveys
web/uploads/surveys/*
!web/uploads/surveys/.gitkeep
```